# How to check if URL param exists

Tags: go, gorilla, mux

I have to check if URL param exists before to do some type of validation. How can i do this?

if param come empty like this: http://myurl.com?myparam= then myParam == "" is true, but if the url come this way http://myurl.com (with out params) then myParam == "" also is true... so i need some way to validate if param come in the url

```
# example
# http://myurl.com?myparam=johndoe

// validate if param exists, here i dont know how to do
#
#


// then do some validation
func validateMyParamIsNotNumber(r *http.Request, resultMessage *string) {
    myParam := r.FormValue("myparam")

    if myParam != ""  && isNotNumber(product) {
        *resultMessage = "The myparam filter must be a number"
        return
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Check for presence of the key in [Request.Form](https://godoc.org/net/http#Request.Form) using [map index with multiple assignment](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Index_expressions). Parse the form before checking the map.

```
func validateMyParamIsNotNumber(r *http.Request, resultMessage *string) {
    r.ParseForm()
    _, hasMyParam := r.Form["myparam"]
    ...
```